# How do I prevent my HTTP module from intercepting all CSS/JS/Image Http request?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have created an HTTP module for some user related thing. I have declared my module in web config.

Now thing module intercepts all my HTTP request also, like request for CSS, Js, Images, Templates n more.

Is there any way I can pass an exclusion list, a regex or something for this ?

Pls advice.